# Interpret XMP-Metadata in ALAssetRepresentation

Tags: ios, ios6, alassetslibrary, cifilter, ciimage

When a user makes some changes (cropping, red-eye removal, ...) to photos in the built-in **Photos.app** on iOS, the changes are not applied to the `fullResolutionImage` returned by the corresponding `ALAssetRepresentation`.

However, the changes are applied to the `thumbnail` and the `fullScreenImage` returned by the `ALAssetRepresentation`.
Furthermore, information about the applied changes can be found in the `ALAssetRepresentation`'s   metadata dictionary via the key `@"AdjustmentXMP"`.

I would like to apply these changes to the `fullResolutionImage` myself to preserve consistency. I've found out that on **iOS6+** `CIFilter`'s `filterArrayFromSerializedXMP:                              inputImageExtent:error:` can convert this XMP-metadata to an array of `CIFilter`'s:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep; 
NSString *xmpString = rep.metadata[@"AdjustmentXMP"];
NSData *xmpData = [xmpString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:rep.fullResolutionImage];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *filterArray = [CIFilter filterArrayFromSerializedXMP:xmpData 
                                             inputImageExtent:image.extent 
                                                        error:&error];
if (error) {
     NSLog(@"Error during CIFilter creation: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

for (CIFilter *filter in filterArray) {
     [filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
     image = [filter outputImage];
}
```

However, this works only for some filters (cropping, auto-enhance) but not for others like red-eye removal. In these cases, the `CIFilter`s have no visible effect. Therefore, my questions:

- Is anyone aware of a way to create red-eye removal `CIFilter`? (In a way consistent with the Photos.app. The filter with the key `kCIImageAutoAdjustRedEye` is not enough. E.g., it does not take parameters for the position of the eyes.)
- Is there a possibility to generate and apply these filters under iOS 5?

Comment: This link is to another Stackoverflow question which provides an algorithm for red eye. It's not much but it's a start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133675/red-eye-reduction-algorithm

Comment: On iOS 7 the code listed correctly applies red-eye removal filter (CIRedEyeCorrections internal filter).

Answer (score 2):

```
ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [[self assetAtIndex:index] defaultRepresentation];

// Create a buffer to hold the data for the asset's image
uint8_t *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(representation.size); // Copy the data from the asset into the buffer
NSUInteger length = [representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset: 0.0  length:representation.size error:nil];

if (length==0)
    return nil;

// Convert the buffer into a NSData object, and free the buffer after.

NSData *adata = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:representation.size freeWhenDone:YES];

// Set up a dictionary with a UTI hint. The UTI hint identifies the type
// of image we are dealing with (that is, a jpeg, png, or a possible
// RAW file).

// Specify the source hint.

NSDictionary* sourceOptionsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

(id)[representation UTI], kCGImageSourceTypeIdentifierHint, nil];

// Create a CGImageSource with the NSData. A image source can
// contain x number of thumbnails and full images.

CGImageSourceRef sourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef) adata,  (CFDictionaryRef) sourceOptionsDict);

[adata release];

CFDictionaryRef imagePropertiesDictionary;

// Get a copy of the image properties from the CGImageSourceRef.

imagePropertiesDictionary = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(sourceRef,0, NULL);

CFNumberRef imageWidth = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(imagePropertiesDictionary, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth);

CFNumberRef imageHeight = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(imagePropertiesDictionary, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight);

int w = 0;

int h = 0;

CFNumberGetValue(imageWidth, kCFNumberIntType, &w);

CFNumberGetValue(imageHeight, kCFNumberIntType, &h);

// Clean up memory

CFRelease(imagePropertiesDictionary);
```