# ALAsset defaultRepresentation fullResolutionImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, ios7, alassetslibrary

I have an issue with new iOS 7 photo filters feature. 
I have a photolibrary in my app. While I showing photo's thumbnails in UICollectionView I receive images with filters and crops already applied. There are two methods that return "ready for use" images:

- `[asset thumbnail]`
- `[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]`

On the contrary, when I want to share fullsize image I receive unchanged photo without any filters:

- `[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]`
- Read image data through [getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetRepresentation/getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:)

Is it possible to get a fullsize image with filter appropriate applied?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Please restate the question so we can understand exactly what you expect to achieve.

Comment: You have a spelling error in line 5 of your code: "if (adjusment)". Have you thought about posting your possible solution as answer? So we can vote it up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So far I figured out only one way to get what I want. All assets store their modification (like filters, crops and etc) info in the metadata dictionary by the key `@"AdjustmentXMP"`. We're able to interpret this data and apply all filters to the `fullResolutionImage` like in this [SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305020/interpret-xmp-metadata-in-alassetrepresentation) Here is my complete solution:

```
...
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef fullResImage = [assetRepresentation fullResolutionImage];
NSString *adjustment = [[assetRepresentation metadata] objectForKey:@"AdjustmentXMP"];
if (adjustment) {
    NSData *xmpData = [adjustment dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:fullResImage];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *filterArray = [CIFilter filterArrayFromSerializedXMP:xmpData
                                                 inputImageExtent:image.extent
                                                            error:&error];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    if (filterArray && !error) {
        for (CIFilter *filter in filterArray) {
            [filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
            image = [filter outputImage];
        }
        fullResImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:[image extent]];
    }   
}
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:fullResImage
                                      scale:[assetRepresentation scale]
                                orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[assetRepresentation orientation]];
```

Comment: With iOS 8, I can't find @"AdjustmentXMP" inside the metadata dictionary.

Comment: @Andree in iOS 8 getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: already give you an adjusted photo. No need to do something.

Comment: @Wisors that's *kindof* true. But there's an Apple bug where the non-adjusted photo is returned if you grab it quickly enough after making edits. http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6416588328665088